# File path to the server not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanted to save file to my server location. But when I give file save it in to my computer location it's working BUT when I give it to server location it's not working..

This one is working

```
string savedFileName = 
       Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp\", Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileExtension);
```

This one not working

```
//string savedFileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), fileName);
```

Comment: do you get any errors? Is there a /uploadFiles folder with appropriate write permission? Show us the saving code too.

Comment: As @Valamas mentioned, make sure the folder exists **and you have permissions to write to that directory**.

Comment: @Valamas-AUS thanks... Solved it ,thats write permission

Comment: no worries. recommend deleting the question if you can. Most likely a duplicate.

Comment: Plus I recommend you start reading. See, it is not "not working", it is throwing an exception and if you would have cared to read it it would very likely have told you "access violation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have "Write" permission on your destination folder i.e. "UploadedFiles".

If don`t have permission, go to server control panel where you have hosted your application and go to FileManager and select your folder and change the permission for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code its work..

```
   string savedFileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/"), fileName)
```

And also make sure this folder is exists and has write or read permission as well.